# Show button and text in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I tried to code in react native today and tried to write a program with a button and a text that changes with every press:

```
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Button, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';


export default () => {

const onButton = () =>
{
  myResult(10);
}

return (
  <Text>Hello World</Text>  

  <Button
  onPress={onButton}
  title="Click Here to calculate"
  color="black"
  />
)
}
```

It gives me this error:

```
Parsing error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</>?
```

If I comment the text class or the button class like that:
`//<Text>Hello World</Text>`
the other class would work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The error message that you quote is very explicit about both what the problem is, and how to fix it. Could you expand on which part of it you don't understand?

Comment: Besides the two answers below, I think you'll also need to replace `onPress={onButton}`by `onPress={()=>{onButton()}}`, otherwise your function will be called even before the button is clicked.

Answer (score 4):

You can't render multiple component like that. Like the error message said, you have to wrap them in an enclosing tag.

```
<View>
    <Text>Hello World</Text>  

    <Button
      onPress={onButton}
      title="Click Here to calculate"
      color="black"
    />
</View>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are returning 2 components, in react you must return just one component, so your code you could wrapping in two ways:

```
<View>
    <Text>Hello World</Text>  

    <Button
      onPress={onButton}
      title="Click Here to calculate"
      color="black"
    />
</View>
```

Or using `Fragment` component of react that will no add a node in your component tree

```
//You can use Fragment as <></> or <React.Fragment></React.Fragment>
<>
    <Text>Hello World</Text>  

    <Button
      onPress={onButton}
      title="Click Here to calculate"
      color="black"
    />
</>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to wrap it in a `<View>` tag, as mentioned in the other two answers.

---

Here is a fun solution, you can even return an array.

Example:

```
return [
        <Text>Hello World</Text>, 
        <Button 
           onPress={onButton}
           title="Click Here to calculate"
           color="black" 
        />
];
```